# How to get textField's input and replace it with a text inside of another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm creating a project where a user selects a title for something such as their team or management, but then it'll exit the window that asks them like their name and such and it'll replace the user input.

Such as -
I input the name "Amy" and then it'll exit the window but it'll replace the Empty Team Slot label with Amy (who knows why?), but the Empty Team Slot is in a different JFrame and the JTextField is in another.

I've already set up a String to get the textField.getText() in the selection name window, but I need to find out a way to show that getText in the other frame with the Empty Team Slot.

Also, an additional help/info, how to make it so it'll exit the window when they press Apply Changes yet it'll apply the name and such.

I've already tried inputting the textField.getText() into the teams page yet not any luck.

Tried researching or reaching out to any of the coders' friends of mine.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String currentText = textField.getText();
```

```
JLabel lblEmptyProjectSlot = new JLabel("Empty Team Slot");

        lblEmptyProjectSlot.setBounds(105, 299, 275, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEmptyProjectSlot);
```

If I need to give more additional info I will just reply. :)

- No error messages
  It'll replace the Empty Team Slot with Amy which specifies that it's Amy's team, I don't need it so it'll say Amy's Team just Amy is fine.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Please show more code